# UITextView link is clickable, but when I click it, Safari doesn't open

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have set this two important variable for clickable link, but when I click the content link in the `UITextView`, Safari doesn't open.

Anybody know what the problem is?

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITextView *attachmentDescription;

{
    self.attachmentDescription.editable = NO;
    self.attachmentDescription.dataDetectorTypes =UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
}
```

Comment: are you taken textview in xib?

Comment: How did you create that property? Drag and drop from the interface editor?

Comment: once check xib ,IBOutlet connected or not?